# Reading whitespace with getline() doesn't work

Tags: c++, whitespace, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class sheet
{
    public:
        void setname();
        string getname();
    private:
        string name;
};

void sheet::setname()
{
        cout << ">" ;
        getline(cin,name);
        return ;
}
```

So i have a code like this^. And in the main funtion i have

```
sheet Personel;
Personel.setname();
```

But when i run my code it prints the '>' but getline doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just saying "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What do you expect to happen? What happens?

Comment: Usually a function called "setX" takes the value as the parameter which is obtained externally. Your get function could return `name` by const reference if it does that without modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I solved it. It reads some leftover '\n' previously in main.

Comment: Use cin.ignore() I believe to get an unwanted characters that are left over that you know are there, or use it when you notice that a question doesn't let you answer and directly skips it.